# How can I handle date-dependent status activation on a DB?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, talend

My problem is two-fold. I'm trying to handle it as elegantly as possible.

Give a date of the below format,

```
 YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss
```

how can I find the corresponding date a variable number of days away? For example, if given a date, I need to be able to find the corresponding date of that format "x" days away from then.

This generated date is what I would store in an activation_date column in the database. Then I want to query the database nightly to see if it is that date yet. If so, I would change the status of an item in a different column from pending to active.

This seems like the best way to handle my problem but it doesn't seem like it will be very straightforward to solve.

The alternative would be that I create a days_till_activation column in the DB and have a script that nightly decrements the value in that column for each entry until zero is reached. Once zero is reached, the script would change the status. The problem with this is that is seems like a really poor way to deal with the database. It involves a lot of writing to the database rather than doing it only when required.

Anyway, any thoughts would be appreciated. I need to handle the solution in java but pseudocode would be fine.

Comment: Do you want `days` difference between current day and the date stored?

Answer (score 1):

> Give a date of the below format,
>
> ```
> YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss
> ```

That's your first problem. **Don't think of dates in a particular format.** Make sure your database schema uses an appropriate date/time field type, and use an appropriate type in your Java code too. You should never need to see a string representation unless you're showing it to the user.

Fortunately, this part is easy:

> how can I find the corresponding date a variable number of days away?

I would suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to represent your date and time values as far as possible. That makes it easy:

```
LocalDate date = ...;
LocalDate activation = date.plusDays(activationDays);
```

You *could* just use `java.util.Date`/`Calendar` for this, but I would suggest converting to Joda Time types as soon as you can when you extract data from your database, and convert back to the native Java types at the last possible moment. That way you can avoid the hideousness of the Java types for as much of the time as possible.

Comment: +1 for pointing out using `date/time` fields in database and in `java` code..and also for pointing at Joda Time..it is really a way out from lots of Date\Time problems

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this I would opt for an integer type column holding the expiration timestamp (`currentTimeMilis() + x * MILLIES_PER_DAY`) making your query very easy (`where expiration < ?` binding the parameter to `currentTimeMilis()`.)

Chosing for a date/time type column adds complexity to your solution making the behaviour dependent on the database install (OS language changes can make a difference.)